# How to create PhoneStateListener that works in both Doze Mode and Power Saving Mode?

Tags: java, android, phone-state-listener, android-doze

When device enters Doze mode or Power Saving mode my PhoneStateListener stops to work. Also I need to register PhoneStateListener on device reboot. I don't want to use BroadcastReceiver because it is not recommended anymore, see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think BroadcastReceiver are not recommended is the right definition at this point , its just has more [limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts) such as register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in the manifest and according to docs :

> - Apps can continue to register for explicit broadcasts in their manifests
> - Apps can use `Context.registerReceiver()` at runtime to register a receiver for any broadcast, whether implicit or explicit.

Doze mode has few [restrictions](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#restrictions) but it provide a solution for firing alarms at Doze mode an Power Saving Mode using `AlarmManager` :

> If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()`.

You should about [setAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%2520long,%2520android.app.PendingIntent)) and [setExactAndAllowWhileIdle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(int,%2520long,%2520android.app.PendingIntent)) and decide which one is relevant for you .